# In UEFA competitions, could a team forfeit a game and still qualify?

Tags: football, qualifying

My understanding is that, in UEFA football games, a forfeiting team is awarded a 0-3 score (defeat) against the opposing team.
If, in a competition, a team wins the first game 4-0, could the same team decide to forfeit the second leg, so losing 3-0 and assuring it would still qualify to the next round? (I understand this is hypothetical)

Comment: Depends way too much on what competition you're asking about, and there are about as many regulations on this as there are competitions to run them.

Comment: Related: [In which game was a limited overs innings declared to prevent an opponent from qualifying?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7465/in-which-game-was-a-limited-overs-innings-declared-to-prevent-an-opponent-from-q/). tl;dr: somebody tried this trick. They were thrown out of the competition.

Comment: The tag is for football

Comment: Sure, but it's a fairly good guide as to how other organising bodies would treat this kind of stunt.

Comment: This is also a duplicate of a previous question, which uses UEFA as an explicit example, https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/is-a-match-forfeit-always-scored-as-3-0-regardless-of-situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you explicitly mentioned the UEFA, I'll answer your question using their regulations. And the answer is no. That's not possible.

**The UEFA does not allow this behavior in their competitions.**

If a team does not play a match or is responsible for it to not take place in any way that team will be disqualified and fined. This means the opponent will advance to the next round, if applicable.

The rules for the [Europa League](https://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/55/82/82/2558282_DOWNLOAD.pdf) and [Champions League](https://www.uefa.com/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/55/82/79/2558279_DOWNLOAD.pdf) are the same in this particular case.
Article 26 in the EL and 28 in the CL:

> Refusal to play and similar cases
>
> If a club refuses to play or is responsible for a match not taking
>   place or not being played in full, the UEFA Control, Ethics and
>   Disciplinary Body declares the match forfeited and disqualifies the
>   club concerned in combination with the following fines (...)